# 'pageNumber' value in data parameter is not passed through $.ajax() call made

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have been trying to do pagination using jquery to display item details through an eBay API using PHP as the back end. The other parameters are passed easily to the PHP file except for the page number parameter in the data section of the $.ajax() call and hence even though the call is successful, only the first page is shown for every page clicked. Can anybody point out what is going wrong?

Here is a part of the code:

```
function paginatingRetrieval(pageno)
    {
        alert("calling the page number "+pageno);
        alert("the page is "+pages);
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "ResponseProg.php",
            datatype: "json",
            data:
            {
                keywords:$("#kw").val(),
                Results:$("#rslts option:selected").val(),
                SortOrder:$("#srt option:selected").val(),
                MinPrice:$("#mn").val(),
                MaxPrice:$("#mx").val(),
                New:$("#Nw").is(':checked') ? $("#Nw").val() : "notset",
                Used:$("#Usd").is(':checked') ? $("#Usd").val() : "notset",
                Very_Good:$("#Vg").is(':checked') ? $("#Vg").val() : "notset",
                Good:$("#Gd").is(':checked') ? $("#Gd").val() : "notset",
                Acceptable:$("#Ac").is(':checked') ? $("#Ac").val() : "notset",
                ListingType_1:$("#bin").is(':checked') ? $("#bin").val() : "notset",
                ListingType_2:$("#actn").is(':checked') ? $("#actn").val() : "notset",
                ListingType_3:$("#Ca").is(':checked') ? $("#Ca").val() : "notset",
                ReturnsAcceptedOnly:$("#Ra").is(':checked') ? $("#Ra").val() : "notset",
                FreeShippingOnly:$("#Fs").is(':checked') ? $("#Fs").val() : "notset",
                ExpeditedShippingAvailable:$("#Esa").is(':checked') ? $("#Esa").val() : "notset",
                MaxHandlingTime:$("#Mhtd").val(),
                pageNumber:pageno
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                JSONObj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                $("#rtrn").html("data successfully retrieved for page number "+pageno+"\n "+data);
                //contentProvider("#rtrn");
            },
            error: function()
            {
                $("#rtrn").html("Data not retrieved successfully");
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is part of the HTML code that is involved in the calling of the function:

```
            var page='<ul class="pagination" id="pager">'+
                            '<li id="prev">'+
                            '<a href="#" id="prev" aria-label="Previous">'+
                            '<span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>'+
                            '</a>'+
                            '</li>';
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                var index=ind+i;
                page+='<li id="'+index+'"><a href="javascript:paginatingRetrieval('+index+')" id="page'+index+' value="'+index+'">'+index+'</a></li>';
            }
            page+='<li>'+
                '<a href="#" id="next" aria-label="next">'+
                    '<span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>'+
                    '</a>'+
                '</li>'+
                '</ul>';
            return page;
```

I am trying to display only 5 pages as of now and not working on the previous and next buttons. Every time I click a button on the pagination, the same result is displayed.

This is the JSON retrieved on giving the keyword:'IKEA' min price:0 max price:100 and max handling time:7 and every time a pagination button is clicked say 2, 3 etc it always shows the first page.

```
{
"ack": "Success",
"resultCount": 23624,
"pageNumber": 1,
"itemCount": 5,
"item0": {
    "basicInfo": {
        "title": "IKEA HOLMO Floor lamp light white Rice paper shade Modern Contemporary New",
        "viewitemURL": "http://www.ebay.com/itm/IKEA-HOLMO-Floor-lamp-light-white-Rice-paper-shade-Modern-Contemporary-New-/371340016191?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0",
        "galleryURL": "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mmkMl3fVtDHRy80P_StIYgg/140.jpg",
        "pictureURLSuperSize": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/-44AAOxygPtS57Qk/$_12.JPG",
        "convertedCurrentPrice": 6.99,
        "shippingServiceCost": 10.99,
        "conditionDisplayName": "New",
        "listingType": "StoreInventory",
        "location": "Baltimore,MD,USA",
        "categoryName": "Lamps",
        "topRatedListing": "true"
    },
    "sellerInfo": {
        "sellerUserName": "jx035md",
        "feedbackScore": 10357,
        "positiveFeedbackPercent": 100,
        "feedbackRatingStar": "YellowShooting",
        "topRatedSeller": "true",
        "sellerStoreName": "",
        "sellerStoreURL": ""
    },
    "shippingInfo": {
        "shippingType": "FlatDomesticCalculatedInternational",
        "shipToLocations": [
            "US",
            "CA",
            "GB",
            "AU",
            "AT",
            "BE",
            "FR",
            "DE",
            "IT",
            "JP",
            "ES",
            "TW",
            "NL",
            "CN",
            "HK",
            "MX",
            "DK",
            "RO",
            "SK",
            "BG",
            "CZ",
            "FI",
            "HU",
            "LV",
            "LT",
            "MT",
            "EE",
            "GR",
            "PT",
            "CY",
            "SI",
            "SE",
            "KR",
            "ID",
            "ZA",
            "TH",
            "IE",
            "PL",
            "RU",
            "IL"
        ],
        "expeditedShipping": "false",
        "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
        "returnsAccepted": "true",
        "handlingTime": 1
    }
},
"item1": {
    "basicInfo": {
        "title": "New IKEA Ektorp loveseat Idemo beige slipcover cover 2-seat sofa ",
        "viewitemURL": "http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-IKEA-Ektorp-loveseat-Idemo-beige-slipcover-cover-2-seat-sofa-/331569715403?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0",
        "galleryURL": "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/m31xhZMrlY5bQeEWqRt87wQ/140.jpg",
        "pictureURLSuperSize": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/9sgAAOSwKrhVaf2Z/$_12.JPG",
        "convertedCurrentPrice": 75,
        "shippingServiceCost": 0,
        "conditionDisplayName": "New other (see details)",
        "listingType": "AuctionWithBIN",
        "location": "Houghton,MI,USA",
        "categoryName": "Slipcovers",
        "topRatedListing": "false"
    },
    "sellerInfo": {
        "sellerUserName": "jmack55",
        "feedbackScore": 149,
        "positiveFeedbackPercent": 100,
        "feedbackRatingStar": "Turquoise",
        "topRatedSeller": "false",
        "sellerStoreName": "",
        "sellerStoreURL": ""
    },
    "shippingInfo": {
        "shippingType": "Free",
        "shipToLocations": [
            "US",
            "CA",
            "GB",
            "AU",
            "AT",
            "BE",
            "FR",
            "DE",
            "IT",
            "JP",
            "ES",
            "TW",
            "NL",
            "CN",
            "HK",
            "MX",
            "DK",
            "RO",
            "SK",
            "BG",
            "CZ",
            "FI",
            "HU",
            "LV",
            "LT",
            "MT",
            "EE",
            "GR",
            "PT",
            "CY",
            "SI",
            "SE",
            "KR",
            "ID",
            "TH",
            "IE",
            "PL",
            "RU",
            "IL",
            "NZ"
        ],
        "expeditedShipping": "true",
        "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
        "returnsAccepted": "false",
        "handlingTime": 3
    }
},
"item2": {
    "basicInfo": {
        "title": "Floor Lamp Light Ikea Holmo with Rice Paper Shade Modern Contemporary NEW ",
        "viewitemURL": "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Floor-Lamp-Light-Ikea-Holmo-Rice-Paper-Shade-Modern-Contemporary-NEW-/371342969642?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0",
        "galleryURL": "http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mcqESoYv3si3-U-n24F3LLQ/140.jpg",
        "pictureURLSuperSize": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/lNsAAOxy4dBRnOxf/$T2eC16F,!ygE9s7HHgu8BRnO)fjdsg~~60_3.JPG",
        "convertedCurrentPrice": 19.99,
        "shippingServiceCost": 0,
        "conditionDisplayName": "New",
        "listingType": "StoreInventory",
        "location": "USA",
        "categoryName": "Lamps",
        "topRatedListing": "true"
    },
    "sellerInfo": {
        "sellerUserName": "homeanddecor",
        "feedbackScore": 22218,
        "positiveFeedbackPercent": 99.4,
        "feedbackRatingStar": "YellowShooting",
        "topRatedSeller": "true",
        "sellerStoreName": "",
        "sellerStoreURL": ""
    },
    "shippingInfo": {
        "shippingType": "Free",
        "shipToLocations": "US",
        "expeditedShipping": "true",
        "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
        "returnsAccepted": "true",
        "handlingTime": 1
    }
},
"item3": {
    "basicInfo": {
        "title": "FILLSTA Table White Lamp ",
        "viewitemURL": "http://www.ebay.com/itm/FILLSTA-Table-White-Lamp-/331571817429?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0",
        "galleryURL": "http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mQm7GQdmQ4cM4pCKUWo0h1g/140.jpg",
        "pictureURLSuperSize": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/5DEAAOSwl8NVbMuF/$_12.JPG",
        "convertedCurrentPrice": 7.99,
        "shippingServiceCost": 0,
        "conditionDisplayName": "Used",
        "listingType": "Auction",
        "location": "Jacksonville,FL,USA",
        "categoryName": "Lamps",
        "topRatedListing": "false"
    },
    "sellerInfo": {
        "sellerUserName": "clee9064",
        "feedbackScore": 84,
        "positiveFeedbackPercent": 100,
        "feedbackRatingStar": "Blue",
        "topRatedSeller": "false",
        "sellerStoreName": "",
        "sellerStoreURL": ""
    },
    "shippingInfo": {
        "shippingType": "Calculated",
        "shipToLocations": [
            "US",
            "CA",
            "GB",
            "AU",
            "AT",
            "BE",
            "FR",
            "DE",
            "IT",
            "JP",
            "ES",
            "TW",
            "NL",
            "CN",
            "HK",
            "MX",
            "DK",
            "RO",
            "SK",
            "BG",
            "CZ",
            "FI",
            "HU",
            "LV",
            "LT",
            "MT",
            "EE",
            "GR",
            "PT",
            "CY",
            "SI",
            "SE",
            "KR",
            "ID",
            "TH",
            "IE",
            "PL",
            "RU",
            "IL",
            "NZ"
        ],
        "expeditedShipping": "true",
        "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
        "returnsAccepted": "true",
        "handlingTime": 2
    }
},
"item4": {
    "basicInfo": {
        "title": "IKEA HOLMO Floor lamp light white Rice paper shade Modern Contemporary brand new",
        "viewitemURL": "http://www.ebay.com/itm/IKEA-HOLMO-Floor-lamp-light-white-Rice-paper-shade-Modern-Contemporary-brand-new-/171742977475?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0",
        "galleryURL": "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/myaABTkDgQyLgI55COQjcIA/140.jpg",
        "pictureURLSuperSize": "http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/OTYwWDU0MA==/z/KzIAAOSwBahVHbbq/$_3.JPG",
        "convertedCurrentPrice": 8.95,
        "shippingServiceCost": 0,
        "conditionDisplayName": "New",
        "listingType": "StoreInventory",
        "location": "Longwood,FL,USA",
        "categoryName": "Lamps",
        "topRatedListing": "true"
    },
    "sellerInfo": {
        "sellerUserName": "xclusive-deals-com",
        "feedbackScore": 740,
        "positiveFeedbackPercent": 100,
        "feedbackRatingStar": "Purple",
        "topRatedSeller": "true",
        "sellerStoreName": "",
        "sellerStoreURL": ""
    },
    "shippingInfo": {
        "shippingType": "Calculated",
        "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
        "expeditedShipping": "true",
        "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
        "returnsAccepted": "true",
        "handlingTime": 1
    }
}
```

}

here is the php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')    
{
    $call="";
    $response;
    $c=0;
    $l=0;
    $pms=0;
    $url="http://svcs.eBay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?siteid=0&SECURITY-APPNAME=Universi-9b52-4bc2-b847-385688b5de53&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=XML";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
    {
        $call.=$url;
        if(isset($_GET["keywords"]) and $_GET["keywords"]!='' and $_GET["keywords"] != 'notset')
        {
            $enc = urlencode(utf8_encode($_GET["keywords"]));
            $call.="&keywords=".$enc;
        }
        if(isset($_GET["Results"]) and $_GET["Results"]!='' and $_GET["Results"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=".$_GET["Results"];                 
        }
        if(isset($_GET["SortOrder"]) and $_GET["SortOrder"]!='' and $_GET["SortOrder"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&sortOrder=".$_GET["SortOrder"];
        }
        if(isset($_GET["MinPrice"]) and $_GET["MinPrice"]!='' and $_GET["MinPrice"] != 'notset')
        {                        $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=MinPrice&itemFilter(".$pms.").value=".$_GET["MinPrice"];
        $pms++;
        }
    if(isset($_GET["MaxPrice"]) and $_GET["MaxPrice"]!='' and     $_GET["MaxPrice"] != 'notset')
        {
           $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(".$pms.").value=".$_GET["MaxPrice"];
            $pms++;
        }
        $numhand = $_GET["MaxHandlingTime"];
        if($numhand != "")
    {
        if(in_array($numhand,$_GET))
        {
            if(isset($_GET["MaxHandlingTime"]) and $_GET["MaxHandlingTime"]!='' and $_GET["MaxHandlingTime"] != 'notset')
            {
                $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=MaxHandlingTime&itemFilter(".$pms.").value=".$_GET["MaxHandlingTime"];
                $pms++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(in_array("1000",$_GET) || in_array("3000",$_GET) || in_array("4000",$_GET) || in_array("5000",$_GET) || in_array("6000",$_GET))
    {
        $condition="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=Condition";
        $call.=$condition;  
        if(isset($_GET["New"]) and $_GET["New"]!='' and $_GET["New"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$c.")=".$_GET["New"];
            $c++;
        }
        if(isset($_GET["Used"]) and $_GET["Used"]!='' and $_GET["Used"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$c.")=".$_GET["Used"];
            $c++;                   
        }
        if(isset($_GET["Very_Good"]) and $_GET["Very_Good"]!='' and $_GET["Very_Good"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$c.")=".$_GET["Very_Good"];
            $c++;                   
        }
        if(isset($_GET["Good"]) and $_GET["Good"]!='' and $_GET["Good"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$c.")=".$_GET["Good"];
            $c++;                   
        }
        if(isset($_GET["Acceptable"]) and $_GET["Acceptable"]!='' and $_GET["Acceptable"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$c.")=".$_GET["Acceptable"];                  
        }
        $pms++;
    }
    if( in_array("FixedPrice",$_GET) || in_array("Auction",$_GET) || in_array("Classified",$_GET))
    {       
        $listing="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=ListingType";          
        $call.=$listing;
        if(isset($_GET["ListingType_1"]) and $_GET["ListingType_1"]!='' and $_GET["ListingType_1"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$l.")=".$_GET["ListingType_1"];
            $l++;                   
        }
        if(isset($_GET["ListingType_2"]) and $_GET["ListingType_2"]!='' and $_GET["ListingType_2"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$l.")=".$_GET["ListingType_2"];
            $l++;                   
        }
        if(isset($_GET["ListingType_3"]) and $_GET["ListingType_3"]!='' and $_GET["ListingType_3"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").value(".$l.")=".$_GET["ListingType_3"];                   
        }
        $pms++;
    }
    if(in_array("ReturnsAcceptedOnly",$_GET))
    {       
        if(isset($_GET["ReturnsAcceptedOnly"]) and $_GET["ReturnsAcceptedOnly"]!='' and $_GET["ReturnsAcceptedOnly"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=ReturnsAcceptedOnly&itemFilter(".$pms.").value=true";
            $pms++;
        }
    }   
    if(in_array("FreeShippingOnly",$_GET))
    {
        if(isset($_GET["FreeShippingOnly"]) and $_GET["FreeShippingOnly"]!='' and $_GET["FreeShippingOnly"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=FreeShippingOnly&itemFilter(".$pms.").value=true";
            $pms++;
        }
    }
    if(in_array("Expedited",$_GET))
    {
        if(isset($_GET["ExpeditedShippingAvailable"]) and $_GET["ExpeditedShippingAvailable"]!='' and $_GET["ExpeditedShippingAvailable"] != 'notset')
        {
            $call.="&itemFilter(".$pms.").name=ExpeditedShippingType&itemFilter(".$pms.").value=Expedited";
            $pms++;
        }
    }   
    $call.="&outputSelector[".$pms."]=SellerInfo";
    $pms++;
    $call.="&outputSelector[".$pms."]=PictureURLSuperSize";
    $pms++;
    $call.="&outputSelector[".$pms."]=StoreInfo";
    if(isset($_GET["pageNumber"]))
    {
        $pgno = $_GET["pageNumber"];
        $call.="&paginationInput.pageNumber="+$pgno;
    }
    $response = simplexml_load_file($call);
    //$responseContent = file_get_contents($call);
    //echo $call;
    $entries=$response->paginationOutput->totalEntries;
    $counter=$response->paginationOutput->entriesPerPage;
    $result;
    $items;
    if($entries == 0)
    {
        $result["ack"] = "No results found";
    }
    else
    {
        $result["ack"] = (string)$response->ack;
        $result["resultCount"] = (int)$response->paginationOutput->totalEntries;
        $result["pageNumber"] = (int)$response->paginationOutput->pageNumber;
        $result["itemCount"] = (int)$response->paginationOutput->entriesPerPage;
        $cnt;
        if($entries-$counter < 0)
        {
            $cnt = $entries;
        }
        if($entries-$counter > 0)
        {
            $cnt = $counter;
        }
        for($x=0;$x<$cnt;$x++)
        {
            $basicInfo;
            $basicInfo["title"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->title;
            $basicInfo["viewitemURL"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->viewItemURL;
            $basicInfo["galleryURL"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->galleryURL;
            $basicInfo["pictureURLSuperSize"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->pictureURLSuperSize;
            $basicInfo["convertedCurrentPrice"] = (float)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->sellingStatus->convertedCurrentPrice;
            $basicInfo["shippingServiceCost"] = (float)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost;
            $basicInfo["conditionDisplayName"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->condition->conditionDisplayName;
            $basicInfo["listingType"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->listingInfo->listingType;
            $basicInfo["location"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->location;
            $basicInfo["categoryName"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->primaryCategory->categoryName;
            $basicInfo["topRatedListing"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->topRatedListing;

            $sellerInfo;
            $sellerInfo["sellerUserName"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->sellerInfo->sellerUserName;
            $sellerInfo["feedbackScore"] = (float)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->sellerInfo->feedbackScore;
            $sellerInfo["positiveFeedbackPercent"] = (float)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->sellerInfo->positiveFeedbackPercent;
            $sellerInfo["feedbackRatingStar"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->sellerInfo->feedbackRatingStar;
            $sellerInfo["topRatedSeller"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->sellerInfo->topRatedSeller;
            $sellerInfo["sellerStoreName"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->storeInfo->storeName;
            $sellerInfo["sellerStoreURL"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->storeInfo->storeURL;

            $shippingInfo;
            $shippingInfo["shippingType"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->shippingType;
            if(count((array)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->shipToLocations) > 1)
            {
                $shippingInfo["shipToLocations"] = (array)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->shipToLocations;
            }
            else if(count((array)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->shipToLocations) == 1)
            {
                $shippingInfo["shipToLocations"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->shipToLocations;
            }
            $shippingInfo["expeditedShipping"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->expeditedShipping;
            $shippingInfo["oneDayShippingAvailable"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->oneDayShippingAvailable;
            $shippingInfo["returnsAccepted"] = (string)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->returnsAccepted;
            $shippingInfo["handlingTime"] = (int)$response->searchResult->item[$x]->shippingInfo->handlingTime;

            $itemdetails["basicInfo"]=$basicInfo; 
            $itemdetails["sellerInfo"]=$sellerInfo;
            $itemdetails["shippingInfo"]=$shippingInfo;

            $result["item".$x]=$itemdetails;
        }
    }
    $rsltjson = json_encode($result,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    echo $rsltjson;
}
```

}
?>

this is the code for the form:

```
<div><form id="ecomm" name="ebfrm" action="" method="GET">
            <fieldset>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Key Words<span style="color:red;">*</span>:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="keywords" id="kw" placeholder="Enter keyword"></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Price Range:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="mn" placeholder="from ($)" name="MinPrice" ></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="mx" placeholder="to ($)" name="MaxPrice" ></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Condition:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Nw" name="New" value="1000" >New</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Usd" name="Used" value="3000" >Used</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Vg" name="Very_Good" value="4000" >Very Good</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Gd" name="Good" value="5000" >Good</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Ac" name="Acceptable" value="6000" >Acceptable</label>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Buying Formats:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="bin" name="ListingType_1" value="FixedPrice" >Buy it Now</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="actn" name="ListingType_2" value="Auction" >Auction</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Ca" name="ListingType_3" value="Classified" >Classified Ads</label>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Seller:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Ra" name="ReturnsAcceptedOnly" value="ReturnsAcceptedOnly" >Return Accepted</label>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>    
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Shipping:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Fs" name="FreeShippingOnly" value="FreeShippingOnly" >Free Shipping</label>
            <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="Esa" name="ExpeditedShippingAvailable" value="Expedited" >Expedited shipping available</label>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Mhtd" placeholder="Max handling time(days)" name="MaxHandlingTime" ></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Sort by:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" id="srt" name="SortOrder">
                <option value="BestMatch" >Best Match</option>
                <option value="CurrentPriceHighest" >Price: highest first</option>
                <option value="PricePlusShippingHighest" >Price + Shipping: highest first</option>
                <option value="PricePlusShippingLowest" >Price + Shipping: lowest first</option>
            </select></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2" align="right"><label>Result per page:</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control" id="rslts" name="Results">
                <option value="5" >5</option>
                <option value="10" >10</option>
            </select></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div align="right">
            <button type="button" id="btn" class="btn btn-default" name="clear" onclick="clean();">clear</button>
            <input type="submit" id="sbmt" class="btn btn-primary" name="search" value="search">
            </div>
            </fieldset><br>         
        </form></div>
```

**Update: I solved the problem...it was a typo in the php program**

Comment: Check alert(pageno); in javascript working correctly

Comment: It works well..the problem is that it is the only parameter is the data section of the call that is not being sent. The other parameters are sent properly..the alert shows the proper page number

Comment: put pageNumber:pageno, (add comma at the end of this line)on ajax data section and check it

Comment: ajax data section? but it is already there

Comment: add comma(,) at the end of the line and check it once

Comment: where is the pageno is defined in your code ?

Comment: pageno is sent as a parameter, check the code shown in the second code block

Comment: there is no pageno variable in that block. there is only page and index are there

Comment: index is sent as a parameter to the function as seen in the codeblock